# How to install appAuth in android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm developping an Android app and I want to use this library https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android (https://bintray.com/openid/net.openid/appauth) 
This is the first time I use Android Studio 3.6.3 and I don't understand which files to edit to add this library to my project

Answer (score 2):

I've now in the build.gradle files

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/openid/net.openid"
        }
    }
```

and

```
implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.7.1'
```